# Dependency error not making sense as I thought package reference would mean the correct react version is used

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependencies, node-modules

I'm getting this error when I try to install packages:

```
% npm install         
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: evolution@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.13.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from react-d3-speedometer@1.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-d3-speedometer
npm ERR!   react-d3-speedometer@"^1.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/me/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2021-04-30T17_16_10_808Z-debug.log
```

I see my `packages.json` has both `react@"^16.13.1"` and `react-d3-speedometer@1.0.1`. I thought the `^` would force react to get the latest build. Is this correct or should I change my `packages.json` to `react@"^17.0.0"`.

When I run `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` I get this in the log(I only included sections as the log is too big):

> npm ERR! code 1
> npm ERR! path /Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-sass
> npm ERR! command failed
> npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
> npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0_1/bin/node /Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
> npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/src -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
> npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/src -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o ../src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.cpp
> npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/src -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o ../src/libsass/src/backtrace.cpp

> npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
> npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
> npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0_1/bin/node',
> npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
> npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
> npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
> npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
> npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
> npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
> npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
> npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
> npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
> npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.0.0 | darwin | x64
> npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
> npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
> npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
> npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
> npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
> npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
> npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.16 npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
> npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.0.0
> npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.0.0' ]
> npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.0.0"
> npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.0.0
> npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
> npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
> npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
> npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
> npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
> npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.0.0
> npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-sass/build
> npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-sass/build
> npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
> npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
> npm ERR! (node:81246) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
> npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
> npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
> npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
> npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node/common.gypi',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-gyp',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-sass',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
> npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
> npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
> npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
> npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir /Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0
> npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
> npm ERR! In file included from ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp:2:
> npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator' of type 'const std::__1::basic_string' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string' [-Wrange-loop-analysis]
> npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
> npm ERR!                         ^
> npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string &' to prevent copying
> npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
> npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> npm ERR!                         &
> npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable 'denominator' of type 'const std::__1::basic_string' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string' [-Wrange-loop-analysis]
> npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
> npm ERR!                         ^
> npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string &' to prevent copying
> npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
> npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> npm ERR!                         &
> npm ERR! 2 warnings generated.

> npm ERR! In file included from ../src/libsass/src/values.cpp:3:
> npm ERR! In file included from ../src/libsass/src/values.hpp:4:
> npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator' of type 'const std::__1::basic_string' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string' [-Wrange-loop-analysis]
> npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
> npm ERR!                         ^
> npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string &' to prevent copying
> npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
> npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> npm ERR!                         &
> npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable 'denominator' of type 'const std::__1::basic_string' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string' [-Wrange-loop-analysis]
> npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
> npm ERR!                         ^
> npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string &' to prevent copying
> npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
> npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> npm ERR!                         &
> npm ERR! 2 warnings generated.
> npm ERR! In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
> npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:56:
> npm ERR! In file included from /Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node/node.h:63:
> npm ERR! In file included from /Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node/v8.h:30:
> npm ERR! /Users/me/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:452:38: error: no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'remove_cv'?
> npm ERR!             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t>::value>::Perform(data);
> npm ERR!                                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
> npm ERR!                                      remove_cv
> npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:697:50: note: 'remove_cv' declared here
> npm ERR! template  struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_cv
> npm ERR!                                                  ^
> npm ERR! 1 error generated.
> npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.3.0
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0_1/bin/node" "/Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/Downloads/EvolutionUatFront-main/node_modules/node-sass
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.0.0
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
> npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2021-04-30T19_06_04_928Z-debug.log